# Inserting data on only first row

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I'm inserting data into a datagridview using the following parameterized query:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    textBox1.Text = "insert";
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "prcfunddetails";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fundid", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startdate", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@enddate", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Records successfully inserted");
}
```

The first row is inserted successfully, but the second row throws a unique constraint error (this name already exists).

Note that I've set a unique constraint on `name` column in database.

Is there something wrong with the above code that would cause this error?

---

Thank you Hassan Nisar and lboshuizen sir for your great help. Sorry but still i am getting a same error I think I am doing something wrong. Please help one more time.

```
                textBox1.Text = "insert";
                cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "prcfunddetails";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@action", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@fundid", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@startdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@enddate", SqlDbType.DateTime);

                for (int i = 0; i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters["@action"].Value = textBox1.Text;
                    cmd.Parameters["@fundid"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@startdate"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                    cmd.Parameters["@enddate"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                MessageBox.Show("Records successfully inserted");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep adding parameters to the cmd.

Try this:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(con){
 CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
CommandText = "prcfunddetails"
};

//add the needed parameters to the cmd without the values.
//note: second parameter DbType SHOULD match type of the underlying db-field
cmd.Parameters.Add("@action", SqlDbType.VarChar);
.
.
.

textBox1.Text = "insert"; //I wonder what the effect of "delete" will be :-)
for (var i = 0; i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   //just place the correct values on the parameters
   cmd.Parameters["@action"].Value = textBox1.Text;
   cmd.Parameters["@fundid"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
   //etc//                 
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
//Messagebox out of the loop saves a sweet amount of mouseclicks
MessageBox.Show("Records successfully");
```

Comment: +1. voted up. because you took message box outside :)

Comment: Thank you Hassan Nisar and lboshuizen sir for your great help. Sorry but still i am getting a same error I think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. See above for my new code(in my question).

Comment: Did you check the database and assured that the name is not already yet in the database?

Comment: Yes! Name is already present in my database because Actually my loop inserting a data again on row 1 second time So it giving me unique constraint because the name is already exists. Anyway I done it through other way(but still you can tell the solution how to solve it). Thanks for your help. I marked your answer because of your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here `for-loop`.
You are adding parameters repeatedly.
Add parameters outside for-loop for the SqlCommand while parameters values in for-loop.

```
textBox1.Text = "insert";
cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "prcfunddetails";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@action", SqlDbType.VarChar); //assign valid SqlDbType
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fundid", SqlDbType.VarChar);
//...

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{    
    cmd.Parameters["@action"].Value =  textBox1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters["@fundid"].Value =  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
    //...
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();        
 }
 //one for all.... as indicated in other answer.
 MessageBox.Show("Records successfully inserted");
```

Comment: Can you please write a corrected code here. I don't understand what you means.